# Is there a connected Hausdorff anticompact space that is countably infinite?

Tags: gn.general-topology

*[Cross-posted from MSE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580731)*

Following [Bankston - The total negation of a topological property](https://doi.org/10.1215/ijm/1256048236), a topological space is called *anticompact* if all its compact subsets are finite.  The linked MSE post above has two examples:

**Example 1:** The topology on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the usual Euclidean topology together with the cocountable topology is an uncountable space that is connected anticompact and Hausdorff.

**Example 2:** Given a free ultrafilter $\mathfrak{F}$ on $\mathbb{N}$, take the ultrafilter topology $\tau = \mathfrak{F} \cup \{\emptyset\}$ on $\mathbb{N}$. This is a countably infinite, connected anticompact space.  It is $T_1$, but not $T_2$.

Does there exist a countably infinite connected anticompact space that is Hausdorff?

---

Note that such an example would have to be totally path disconnected.  Also it cannot be sequential, as a consequence of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4567778) to [Is a space where only finite subsets are compact sets always discrete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517411/is-a-space-where-only-finite-subsets-are-compact-sets-always-discrete). In particular, it cannot be first countable.

Comment: $\pi$-base doesn't know any examples.

Comment: It seems that the strongly rigid Brown spaces constructed in this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.12579) have the properties you need: they are connected, countable, Hausdorff and contain no infinite compact sets (because their topology is defined via ultrafilters).

Comment: @TarasBanakh Thanks, this is great.  I'll take a look.  Would you mind adding this comment as an answer so we can mark this as answered?

Comment: @PatrickR Ok, I will write it down, but after updating the paper on arXiv, where I am planning to add the proof that the space is indeed anticompact. By the way, in that paper I would like to cite your question. How should I write your name? Because the nick PatrickP is good for Internet posts but not for old-fashioned papers.

Comment: At least it's better than [Anonymous 4chan poster](https://oeis.org/A180632/a180632.pdf)! (-:

Comment: @StevenClontz Definitely, it is better. By the way, in the updated version of that paper on arxiv, there will be an answer to your question about RC $\Rightarrow$ KC: this implication does not hold.

Comment: @TarasBanakh My full name is Patrick Rabau.

Comment: @PatrickR Thank you. Then I will use this complete name in the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such an example has been constructed by [Banakh and Stelmakh](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.12579).
More precisely, they constructed an anticompact countable connected Hausdorff space which is Brown and strongly rigid.

Comment: Is it fair to say that the fact that the ultrafilters are RK-incomparable is only used in Claim 4 of the paper, to prove strong rigidity? Otherwise to get just an example of anticompact connected Hausdorff countably infinite, the choice of utrafilter could be arbitrary, even the same at each point, and would still give a Brown space.  It follows easily from the ultrafilter property that the only convergent sequences are the eventually constant ones.  Not sure yet about compact subsets in general, but looking forward to the updates to your paper.

Comment: @PatrickR The case of general compact sets reduces to the case of sequences as compact sets in such spaces are metrizable (because they admit a continuous injective map into a second-countable Hausdorff space).

Comment: Yes, perfect.  Compact Hausdorff countable spaces are metrizable.

Comment: I have a question about the "semi-Hausdorff" terminology used in the paper.  Semi-Hausdorff has often been used to mean that distinct points can be separated by disjoint semi-open sets (see e.g. Encyclopedia of Genaral Topology (Hart, Nagata, Vaughan), section a-2, p. 8).  On the other hand, semi Hausdorff has also been used in the past (1960's)  to mean a space with unique sequential limits, but that use is now obsolete, replaced by US-space.  For the meaning in your paper, is there a prior reference to the use of the term?  Or what's the origin of it?

Comment: @PatrickR Semi-Haudorff spaces are called by analogy with semi-regular spaces, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiregular_space

Comment: @PatrickR I have already used this terminology in the paper https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2017-145-03/S0002-9939-2016-13318-2/ (and there was no objections from the referee).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the interesting ams paper.  It's not so easy to find a better name, and since it's already in the literature since 2017, that's a good precedent.  We'll just have "(Banakh) semi-Hausdorff" and "semi-Hausdorff" in the sense of separation by semi-open sets.